# add css in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, magento-2.1.3, less

suppose I need to add following changes in my css:

```
.border{1px solid #cecece}
.box{float:left}
```

I am stucked to add these in my styles, i can only see .less files and not sure how it works.

Answer (score 2):

In your custom theme , Extend your theme CSS file under Magento_Theme\web\css\source _extend.less

you need to create this less file under theme module and then you can write your new styles here or can override existing .

Comment: i already extended theme and have written css in _extend.less but it is not reflecting. I wrote:
`.border{1px solid #cecece}
.box{float:left}`

Comment: run upgrade and static content deploy command , extended less takes effect after these commands

Comment: Another way adding CSS is adding in  \web\css\bootstrap.css

and call this file in head block Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml

 <css src="css/bootstrap.css" />

Comment: ran the deploy command but changes are not visible in any file of css, i checked styles-m.css and others too

Comment: crosscheck your file names like " _extend.less "  and send me your extended path , or have you tried another way ?


this is wrong styling  " .border{1px solid #cecece} "

Comment: how to add these styles in less

Comment: Magento_Theme\web\css\source\ _extend.less 

all styles written in this file will be compiled in styles-m.css/styles-l.css

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to add css to frontend page:

1. Put your css into `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/css/custom.css`.
2. Create xml layout to call your css file, e.g: `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <head>
           <css src="VendorName_ModuleName::custom.css" />
       </head>
   </page>
   ```
3. Run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`